# JavaScript timeout causing postback in aspx C# page - 0x800a1391 – JavaScript runtime error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, timeout

The following JS code shows remaining time, but it causes postback when resetting the time by pressing the Yes button (aspx button). So, when the timing appears on screen, and clicking Yes, it will blank the gridview in the main page and if the main modal popup is up, it will close it, making the user to lose any content. Any idea how to modify it to avoid postback when clicking yes? Or better suggestions?

Code:

```
    function SessionExpireAlert(timeout) {
    var seconds = timeout / 1000;
    document.getElementsByName("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
    document.getElementsByName("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Show Popup before 20 seconds of timeout.
        $find("mpeTimeout").show();
    }, timeout - 20 * 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "Login.aspx";
    }, timeout);
};
function ResetSession() {
    //Redirect to refresh Session.
    window.location = window.location.href;
}
```

Combined solution from:
[How to programatically reset the session time without page refreshing in ASP.Net](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/968618/How-to-programatically-reset-the-session-time-without-page-refreshing-in-ASPNet/)
[Display Session Timeout message before Session expires in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Session-Timeout-message-before-Session-expires-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: Your `ResetSession()` function *explicitly* refreshes the page.  You even say so in the comment in that function.  If you don't want it to do that, then I guess have it do whatever it is you *do* want it to do?  Which is what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution that I combined with the first one. Here is the modified JS code:

```
    var interval;
function SessionExpireAlert(timeout) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    var seconds = timeout / 1000;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;

    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        //Show Popup before 50 seconds of timeout.
        $find("mpeTimeout").show();
    }, timeout - 50 * 1000);
    //if (seconds == 0) {
    //    window.location = "Login.aspx";
    //}
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "Login.aspx";
    }, timeout);
};
function ResetSession() {
    PageMethods.ResetSession(OnSuccess);
    return false;
}
function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
    SessionExpireAlert(response);
}
```

Here the ASPX code:

```
<%-- FOR TIME OUT --%>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/timeOutScript.js"></script>
        <h3>Session Idle:&nbsp;<span id="secondsIdle"></span>&nbsp;seconds.</h3>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake3" runat="server" />
        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeTimeout" BehaviorID ="mpeTimeout" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopupmpeTimeout" TargetControlID="lnkFake3"
            OkControlID="btnYes" CancelControlID="btnNo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground3" OnOkScript = "ResetSession()">
        </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupmpeTimeout" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup3" Style="display: none">
            <div class="header">
                Session Expiring!
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                Your Session will expire in&nbsp;<span id="seconds"></span>&nbsp;seconds.<br />
                Do you want to continue?
            </div>
            <div class="footer" align="right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="yes3" OnClick="btnYes_Click" OnClientClick="return ResetSession()"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="no3" OnClick="btnNo_Click"/> 
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

        <%-- ENDS TIME OUT --%>
```

And here the C# code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    lbUserID.Text = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    UpdateProgress1.AssociatedUpdatePanelID = UpdatePanel1.UniqueID;
    lbLocalTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {

        /*FOR TIMEOUT PURPOSE*/

        Session["Reset"] = true;
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.Config");
        SessionStateSection section = (SessionStateSection)config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
        //int timeout = (int)section.Timeout.TotalMinutes * 1000 * 60;
        int timeout = GetSessionTimeout();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SessionAlert", "SessionExpireAlert(" + timeout + ");", true);

        /*ENDS TIME OUT*/

    }

}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static int ResetSession()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Reset"] = true;
    int timeout = GetSessionTimeout();
    return timeout;
}

private static int GetSessionTimeout()
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.Config");
    SessionStateSection section = (SessionStateSection)config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
    return Convert.ToInt32(section.Timeout.TotalMinutes * 1000 * 60);
}
```

Tag: 0x800a1391 – JavaScript runtime error: ‘PageMethods’ is undefined.